# How to debug javascript in visual studio 2015 RC?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I want to debug javascript in visual studio 2015. I know how to do that in visual studio 2010 as explained in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPmV5lLLSAA). It say that I should detach all processes first and run the application in Internet Explore. However, I can't find the option (detach all) in visual studio 2015. Is there any other method that can be used to debug javascript ?

Comment: Did you find an answer for your question yet? Do you mind sharing?Thx.

Comment: No, I can't find answer, but instead of Visual Studio I use firfox browser to debug javascript or jquery.

Comment: At least in windows 10, you don't have to manually attach or detach to/from a program, when you choose Internet Explorer, VS takes care of that (At least I think so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't find the option (detach all)

This option shows in debug menu after you attach debugger to any process first.

[Client-Side Script Debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7seh8d72.aspx)

[How to: Attach to Script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385613.aspx)

[How to: Enable and Start Script Debugging from Internet Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z959x58c.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

When you run in VS 2015 Debug mode, you will see 'Detach All' under the Debug in the main menu[image]